# how to create PipelineRDD from Java ref type JavaRDD in SparkR?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I'm calling some code in a jar package in SparkR that returns a Java ref type for a JavaRDD. When converting to DataFrame with `createDataFrame(sqlContext, myRDD)` I get an error

```
Error in createDataFrame(sqlContext, myRDD) : unexpected type: jobj
```

What's the right way to take the reference to the RDD in the backend and construct the SparkR DataFrame and use all the lovely R functions it offers?

Comment: You should be able to pass the `JavaRDD` to the `RDD()` constructor before creating the dataframe (like `createDataFrame(sqlContext, RDD(myRDD))`). Can you try this and see if it works?

Comment: yes, that did wrap the backing object but there were various errors when calling functions on the RDD. I've swapped it for a backing DataFrame and wrapped it with dataFrame(...). This has ridded the obscure errors I was getting